# Terminology of p-values and related quantities

Tags: probability, terminology

I have a function of a random variable $f(X)$.  If I find $c$ such that
$$
P(f(X) \leq c) = 0.95,
$$
what are the quantities $c$ and $0.95$ termed?  I'm just a bit confused on terminology.  Would $c$ be called, "the $p95$ value of $f(X)$", or, "the $p95$ value of $X$," or something else?  Also, what we term the value $0.95$?

Comment: Usually $c$ is the one-sided "z" value, at least for normal distributions.

Comment: "percent," "percent rank," ["quantile,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) and "percentile" are terms worth looking up in this context.

Comment: You sometimes see "percentile rank" for "percent rank" but whuber pretty much covers it. (Sometimes other terms are used in particular situations.)